# Multiple git origins/remotes and checkout branches

Tags: git, github

I have multiple forks of a project and I need to branch from a starting point in one of those forks. I'm not certain how one can do this with "git". Basically, the situation is as follows:

- SOURCE project
- I forked SOURCE to MINE
- You forked SOURCE to YOURS
- I have MINE cloned to my LOCAL machine

Now YOURS has a branch called NEXT which I want to work on. How do I checkout YOURS/NEXT in my LOCAL clone? Ideally I will be branching form this point and pushing my changes to MINE, issues a pull request, then you merge them to YOURS.

Comment: Good question.  I was surprised that this was so hard to find.  The `git checkout --help` docs don't mention this use case at all.  I'm surprised that more people don't have a "origin", which is production, such as your SOURCE.  And, a "mine" for local development which you can test remote, clean up, and squash from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

- declare a remote referring to "YOURS"
- declare a local branch which will track `YOURS/NEXT`

That would be:

```
git remote add YOURS /url/for/YOURS/repo
git fetch YOURS
git checkout -b next YOURS/NEXT
```

Comment: Is the `git fetch YOURS` at this point doing the same thing as a `git remote update` does?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the git repositories are published somewhere which you can pull from, you can add remote repositories with `git remote add [name] [URL]`, then you're able to pull changes in from the repository you've added with `git pull [name] [branch]`

A working example of this would be something like

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/git/git.git
git pull upstream maint
```

Comment: I wish to checkout the branch, not pull from it. That is, I don't wish to merge any of their changes into one of my branches, I wish to create a new branch which exactly mirrors theirs.